# convert PDF attachment in application to open it in HTML using PDFBox

Tags: java, attachment, pdfbox

I have an application in which on a certain page user has the facility to upload a PDF file. Later on when user again visit the same page for editing some information and want to view the PDF file attached. That PDF file attached should not be downloaded and then opened. Rather it should directly open in HTML.

Can anyone help me with this?
Can anyone tell me how to use PDFBox for this ? I am a newbie

This application is in java.

Or else is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [iFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), request the PDF file from the server, let the browser use a PDF plugin to display the document.

It's not a trivial problem converting the PDF to HTML and it's never going to look perfect.

Maybe, having the document converted to images like JPG and displaying the images. Conversion on the server can be done by using a VNC server. Open a PDF document in a reader, zoom to a whole page, make a screenshot, crop the image and serve it back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try pdf.js ?

pdf.js is an HTML5 technology experiment that explores building a faithful and efficient Portable Document Format (PDF) renderer without native code assistance.

pdf.js is community-driven and supported by Mozilla Labs. Our goal is to create a general-purpose, web standards-based platform for parsing and rendering PDFs, and eventually release a PDF reader extension powered by pdf.js. Integration with Firefox is a possibility if the experiment proves successful.

For an online demo, visit:

http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Source code : https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js/